# Why start() and poll() in SourceTask are abstract?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

start() and poll() are abstract so in my class which extends from SourceTask I can do the following:

```
public void start(Map<String, String> props, Object anotherParameter)
{
//whatever
}

public List<SourceRecord> poll(Object anotherParameter) throws InterruptedException 
{
//whatever
}
```

But how does the code invoking 'poll(whateverObject)' or 'start(props, whateverObject)' do initialize the whateverObject and reference it properly when invokating it? Because I can not customize the code which invokes this methods, right? Or can I? And if yes, how?

I have seen other Connectors implementations where this is done but I do not understand how it can work.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The methods are abstract because you are meant to override and implement them. That answer isnt limited to the Connect API. Besides that, [start only takes one parameter and poll takes none](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceTask.html#start-java.util.Map-)

Comment: The point of abstract methods is so that users can implement them as they see fit, so long as the implementation satisfies the contract of the method. Then other code can call those methods without worrying about the implementation. With that in mind, I'm not sure where you're actually confused?

Comment: I mean that if the method is abstract I can add parameters to it so instead of implementing: ```public List<SourceRecord> poll()``` I can implement: ```public List<SourceRecord> poll(Object parameter)``` And this would be fine for an abstract method. The problem is I don't have the control of how and when poll() is invoked, so how do I do it for kafka to invoke poll(Object parameter) instead of just poll().

Comment: "_I mean that if the method is abstract I can add parameters to it_" – That is not true. Your `#poll(Object)` method **overloads** the `#poll()` method but does not **override** it.

Answer (score 1):

> start() and poll() are abstract so in my class which extends from SourceTask I can do the following

No, you cannot "do the following" (add parameters) because [those are not the method contracts](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceTask.html#start-java.util.Map-).

You still need to override the actual methods, but then you could call *other* methods (of the same name, with parameters), if you needed to, but those wouldn't be abstract, and have no semantic meaning to be overloaded, so they could be named anything, therefore is just regular Java method calling.

> I can not customize the code which invokes this methods, right?

You cannot*.

<sub>* Unless you want to rebuild Kafka Connect from source</sub>

> The problem is I don't have the control of how and when poll() is invoked

That is correct. Not really clear what parameters you are trying to add, but poll certainly doesn't need anything and any object initialization you need to do should be done via the configuration (the property map passed to the start method)